# Testing local web page on iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, web, webserver, mobile-website

I have an Apache webserver running on my win7 machine that links to some local folder on my hdd. I made a mobile website and i can easily access it from my computer (by going through the webserver). However when i try to access it from my iphone or ipad device, i manage to browse through the files fine, even open images and .js files but when i try open the webpage 90% of the time it times out, and the other 10% of the time it tends to render in very odd ways (as if css of js files are not being loaded.)

I would have thought there was a path error somewhere but in the Apache log i see all the linked files being accessed perfectly fine (i.e GET /Crash%20Test/test2.htm HTTP/1.1" 200 1338).

I'm not that familiar with web servers and networking, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: Can you access it from a separate PC through the local url? What url are you using in your local network?

Comment: any firewall antivirus on your pc?

Comment: Maybe if you could provide a simple deployment diagram of your network that would help people diagnose it.  It also might help you see where the problem is yourself.  The diagram should include all the network interfaces on the host and any devices between the host and the Internet and between the phone and the Internet.

Comment: Hmmm no it does not work from a computer either. I have no firewalls or antivirus running on any laptop. I've been trying to use an ad-hoc network to test to avoid any router or firewall issues. Could this cause the problem? A deployment diagram would be fairly simple, its really just a laptop hard connected to the internet with an ad-hoc wireless network that i'm accessing for these other devices.

Answer (score 0):

Check your html, could be missing a close tag or something silly like that. 
IE is VERY forgiving, so it may appear correctly on your pc, but on safari it wont.

Also check with safari on your PC (enable developer tools) and see if any warnings or errors are given. HTH

Comment: try removing all the external files (ie js files, css file and etc) and see if it works. if so, add each file one at a time and find out which file could be causing problems. Process of elimination.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided deployment diagram, let me try by considering following assumptions

1. You are using XAMPP for local apache webserver
2. It is installed in C Drive
3. Your website folder in in C:\xampp\htdocs\nameofsitefolder
4. Apache is running on default port

If all of the above assumptions are correct. Go to Command Prompt on the computer where the Webserver is installed and type ipconfig.
Make a note of your IP Address. Now on your mobile device replace the word localhost with the ipaddress and add the name of site folder after a slash

For example, if it is `localhost/nameofsitefolder` change it to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/nameofsitefolder`